# <p:datatable/> not refreshing after deleting

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using **JSF** and **Primefaces** in my web application.

I am using **p:datatable id="jobEditTable"** component of primefaces.

In this i have option of deleting some rows.

In datatable i have one delete button on clicking of that button i am showing a 
**p:dialog id="deleteJob"** 
Then i fill some resaon for deleting in **p:dialog** then i am clicking on one command link in **p:dialog** then it calls one action listener where i am clearing the **list of data and creating again.**

And onClick of that command link i am updating jobEditTable and hiding that p:dialog.

```
    <p:datatable id="jobEditTable" value="#{mastersBean.dataList}"..../>
 . . .. . . .  . . .
    <p:commandLink  actionListener="#{tableBean.deleteRow}" update="jobEditTable"  oncomplete="deleteJob.hide()">
               <p:graphicImage value="/images/delete_button.png" />
                 <f:attribute name="model" value="#{tableBean.delCode}"></f:attribute>
                </p:commandLink>
```

All is working fine datatable is also refreshing.

**BUT**  if we search for some jobs before deleting and doing that process than data table is not refreshing. **WHY??**

Means, data table is refreshing if i am not using any filter means without search if i delete some row then data table is refreshing but after searching and on deleting data table is not refreshing..

**Why it is behaving like this ??**

My bean in **view scope**.

This is my **ManagedBean named MastersBean**

```
  public void deleteDetails(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String id=(String)e.getComponent().getAttributes().get("param");
        ........deleting data from database according to id.........
            dataList.clear();

      ..........updating datalist again....................
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();  

        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Successfully Deleted"));  

    }
```

Comment: What version of primefaces are you using? Update to 3.4RC1 if you're not using it, the prior version to this has bugs regarding datatable filtering and sorting.

Answer (score 2):

I think after removing the item from database , you need to remove selected item from your array list too like: `myArrayList.remove(selectedItem);`, dont reload all data again from database !! . 
I had this problem and now it s working well .

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the form around your dataTable in the ajax update:

```
<h:form id="form1">
....
    <p:datatable id="jobEditTable" ..../>
</h:form>

<p:commandLink ... update=":form1"...></p:commandLink>
```

Is the result what you are showing on the dataTable cached in the backing bean? Could you post the source of your backing bean?

Comment: thanks akoskm my command link is in my form but I already tried every combination of updating but it is not working....

Comment: First I think your command link and dataTable should be in separate forms. Then in commandLink update the form around your dataTable. Have you tried this combination? Also, how are you retrieving the data from your dataBase, are you using lazy dataTables?

Comment: could you post the source which is relevant for your dataTable (ie. getters, setters if any, how are you updating the list, etc.). All we can see from the backing bean code is the classical boilerplate code.

Comment: Actually dataList is List of objects when any one deleting the row then i am taking that id and removing from database..and fetching data again and putting in dataList again.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `ListIterator<Object>`:

```
void delete(Object object) {
    ListIterator<Object> iter = myArrayList.listIterator()

    while (iter.hasnext) {
        if (current element == object) {
            ------dataBase call here to delete object----
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
}
```